# how to locate an element to perform a click

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to navigate in site: http://startupnationbook.com/startup-map
I want to click on link of Startups, however I'm not able to locate the element.

I tried:

```
elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Startups')]"));
```

and

```
elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='listtoggle' and contains(text(),'Startups')]"));
```

In both cases I get: "Unable to locate element" error

What is wrong in my expressions and how can I locate the element to perform a click.

Answer (score 2):

The map is in an iframe, you're probably not telling Selenium to look in there.  I would also look for the span tag, and since the id listtoggle is used many times (poor design, making it worthless), just look for contains Startups.

```
// Also should probably use a wait here, in case the page takes too long to load
chromeDriver.switchTo().frame(chromeDriver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
WebElement elem = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Startups')]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://startupnationbook.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main-nav']/li[5]/a")).click();
```

Hope this will work. I have tested.